# escape quotes in inline html of the push function in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, jquery, html

```
<div id="OffLocations" style="width: 100%;"/>
<script>
//JS code...
var officeList = new Array();
<apex:repeat value="{!OfficesOpen}" var="off" >
    officeList.push('<table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid Gray;" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="0px">'
                  +'<tr>'
                  +'<td style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;color: white;font-weight: bold;width:25%;">{!off.Slogan__c}</td>'
                  +'<td style="vertical-align:center;float:left;width:75%;"><i>{!off.Location}</i>'
                  +'<a id=\"xClose\" style="vertical-align:top;float:right;cursor: pointer;">X</a>'
                  +'</td>'
        +'</tr>'
        +'</table>');
    </apex:repeat>

$("#xClose").click(function() {
    alert('Test');
    $("#OffLocations").hide();
});
</script>
```

This code is displaying the values in the page but the inline html < a > element is not working. When I move this tag anywhere out of script block, it is working fine. I've tried using the escape char '\', " etc. How do I escape the double quotes for the id "xClose" to call the function when clicking it or is the fault is somewhere else.

Comment: You are creating multiple `<a>` elements with the same id `xClose` which makes jQuery confuse

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. But I think I've used the "xClose" id only for a single <a> element.

Comment: I'm not sure if `<apex:repeat />` is acceptable inside `<script />`. If it does, when you have more than one record for your `OfficesOpen`, it's creating more than one `<a />`

Comment: Add an event listener on each anchor (since you have multiple in your `apex:repeat`).

Comment: @highfive yes. The <apex:repeat/> tag is acceptable within a script block. You are right, it is fetching more than one records leading to multiple <a> elements.

Comment: @Bachovski if you could help me in adding the event listener, it would be great. In JS using the getElementsByTagName("a") or using the Id in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Have a variable to generate unique Ids

```
<apex:variable var="i" value="{!0}"/> 
<apex:repeat value="{!OfficesOpen}" var="off" >
    officeList.push('<table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid Gray;" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="0px">'
                  +'<tr>'
                  +'<td style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;color: white;font-weight: bold;width:25%;">{!off.Slogan__c}</td>'
                  +'<td style="vertical-align:center;float:left;width:75%;"><i>{!off.Location}</i>'
                  +'<a id="xClose'+{!i}+'" style="vertical-align:top;float:right;cursor: pointer;">X</a>'
                  +'</td>'
        +'</tr>'
        +'</table>');
    <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>

$("a").click(function(){
   var aId = this.id;
   //You can add your logic here based on the id
   ...
   $("#OffLocations").hide();
});
```

UPDATE : added `$("#OffLocations").hide();` so that answer is complete

Comment: Thank you @highfive. So the logic to add there would be      
    $("#OffLocations").hide();
I'm right?

Comment: Oh Common..If that's the only thing you have to do the answer is "yes", I was thinking you have something to do with respect to which `<a />` have been clicked. Anyway this will avoid script break due to duplicate ids

Comment: Yes. For now, I'm using the <a> element to hide the div from the page when the user clicks it. May be later, I'll be trying to add a logic of creating/erasing cookies to track the user interest in viewing the data.

Comment: Ya, in this way you can maintain unique id when you are generating `HTML` dynamically. Have I answered your question @user10345 ?

Comment: Hey thanks again for updating the answer. I'm trying it in my sandbox but it is not hiding the div. I've even given an alert in the click function but not getting response. and aren't we using the xclose[i] id anywhere in the function?

Comment: Code is not tested, please check for any script errors using firebug or similar tool. Since you no need of tracking which `<a />` has been clicked, no need of using `xClosei` here. The purpose of adding `i` is to have unique Ids for them so that code breaks will not happen